# Appending a string in a loop in effective way

Tags: c#

for long time , I always append a string in the following way.

for example if i want to get all the employee names separated by some symbol , in the below example i opeted for pipe symbol.

string final=string.Empty;

```
foreach(Employee emp in EmployeeList)
{
  final+=emp.Name+"|"; // if i want to separate them by pipe symbol
}
```

at the end i do a substring and remove the last pipe symbol as it is not required

```
final=final.Substring(0,final.length-1);
```

Is there any effective way of doing this.

I don't want to appened the pipe symbol for the last item and do a substring again.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `string.Join()` and a Linq projection with `Select()` instead:

```
finalString = string.Join("|", EmployeeList.Select( x=> x.Name));
```

Three reasons why this approach is better:

1. **It is much more concise and readable**
   – it expresses *intend*, not how you
   want to achieve your goal (in your
   case concatenating strings in a
   loop). Using a simple projection with Linq also helps here.
2. **It is optimized by the framework** for
   performance: In most cases `string.Join()` will
   use a `StringBuilder` internally, so
   you are not creating multiple strings that are
   then un-referenced and must be
   garbage collected. Also see: [Do not
   concatenate strings inside loops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. **You don’t have to worry about special cases**. `string.Join()`
   automatically handles the case of
   the “last item” after which you do
   not want another separator, again
   this simplifies your code and makes
   it less error prone.

Comment: thanks , its pretty clean and effective , let me start using this from now.

Answer (score 4):

I like using the aggregate function in linq, such as:

```
string[] words = { "one", "two", "three" };
var res = words.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

Comment: tools , thanks for the answer, i never read about this aggregate , let me read it

Comment: Linq `Aggregate` is almost 2 orders of magnitude slower than `string.Join` (18ms vs 784ms on my sample)

Answer (score 3):

You should [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) your strings.

Example (borrowed from MSDN):

```
using System;

class Sample {
    public static void Main() {
    String[] val = {"apple", "orange", "grape", "pear"};
    String sep   = ", ";
    String result;

    Console.WriteLine("sep = '{0}'", sep);
    Console.WriteLine("val[] = {{'{0}' '{1}' '{2}' '{3}'}}", val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
    result = String.Join(sep, val, 1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine("String.Join(sep, val, 1, 2) = '{0}'", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For building up like this, a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) is probably a better choice.

Comment: Well, I guess this should be a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: @james , ofcourse in real world , we always use string build for appending strings, i just gave as a example here

Answer (score 0):

For your final pipe issue, simply leave the last append outside of the loop

```
int size = EmployeeList.length()
for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
{
     final+=EmployeeList.getEmployee(i).Name+"|";
}
final+=EmployeeList.getEmployee(size-1).Name;
```

Comment: i don't want to do this way , thats why i posted this question.

Comment: **I don't want to appened the pipe symbol for the last item and do a substring again.**

Glad you found your answer, though.

Comment: am i rude in my comment , if so very much sorry. I appreciate your time for answering my question