# How to add strings and show as a full sentence

Tags: c#

I've assigned some string values from a data set to the string `b`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    string b = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
}
```

What I want to do is add those values, and finally show as a sentence.

Example: if "dog", "cat", and "cow" are the values read by the for `loop`, I want to display "dog cat cow" in a message box. How to do that?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(b);`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since it appears you are interested in the String.Join() method this could work perfectly for you. You have plenty of options here but if you want to go that route here's how.

First create an array of the items you are returning then you can simple use the String.Join() method to concatenate the items in the array like so: 
    string separator = whatever seperator you want "," or "|"
    string d = String.Join(separator, animalArray);
    MessageBox.Show(d);

The first thing you'll need to do is make sure you have imported the System.Windows.Forms namespace to enable your ability to call the MessageBox function.

Essentially you are already there with the concatenation of the strings. If you are looking for a cleaner option I would recommend using String.Format() or using the newer method of concatenation by applying a '$' character in front of a string which allows you to simple add your variables between curly braces.

For example: $"Hello my name is {name}."

Comment: Please see my edit for what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the above?
You already have them in your string variable `b`.

Enclose it in `MessageBox.Show();` instead of adding the variable.

```
string b = "";
for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    b += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0] + " " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1] + "\n";
}
MessageBox.Show(b);
```

Comment: well it only adds first name and last name (ex - David Grunpt) of raw 1. I want to show 5 names like that in 5 raws (ex- David Grunpt | Miller Rex | Bla bla | bla bla | bla bla) in a single message box when the loop is complete.

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa see my edit...see if this is what you wanted.

Comment: no http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638044/appending-a-string-in-a-loop-in-effective-way have an answer but i don't understand it!

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa what exactly do you want to have? and what's wrong with my code and that you are stuck onto?...please update your question...it's unclear of what you are asking.

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa i further edited my question...tell me what's not working for you.

Comment: now it's correct.it work. but there's a | mark at the end of the sentence.how to remove it?

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa you only told to show it in this format `(ex- David Grunpt | Miller Rex | Bla bla | bla bla | bla bla)` so i added an extra " | " at the end...okay edited my answer ;) Now you can vote up and mark it as solved if it worked for you.