# Concatenate Strings In For Each Loop

Tags: c#, linq

I am using two for each loops to concatenate values into ONE variable so I can write the value to Word in a Find/Replace method.  My issue is that the below syntax will write the values to the Console twice so this is written to the Console

```
Shirt - SH11
Hat - HA22
Socks - SO33
Shirt - SH11
Hat - HA22
Shirt - SH11
```

What I desire to be written to the console is the values just once like the below:

```
Shirt - SH11
Hat - HA22
Socks - SH11
```

This is my syntax:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ItemsSold", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("ItemIDs", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add("James Jo", "Shirt; Hat; Socks;", "SH11; HA22; SO33");

var itemsSold = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("ItemsSold").Split(new string[] {"; "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var ItemIDs = table.Rows[0].Field<string>("ItemIDs").Split(new string[] {"; "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string displayformat = "";

foreach (string is in itemsSold)
{
    foreach (string id in ItemIDs)
    {
        string s = is.Replace(";", "");
        string d = id.Replace(";", "");
        displayformat += s + " - " + d + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(displayformat);
```

Comment: use `itemsSold.Zip(ItemIDs, (l, r) => l + " - " + r + Environment.NewLine)`

Comment: @RajN wouldnt that return an IEnumerable ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638044/appending-a-string-in-a-loop-in-effective-way to learn about constructing strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to do this in loop, you need to modify it as

```
for(int i=0;i<itemsSold.Count();i++)
{
    string s = itemsSold[i].Replace(";", "");
    string d = ItemIDs[i].Replace(";", "");
    displayformat += s + " - " + d + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

But, please note that this can be easily done with the Zip Method.
Instead of the entire Loop, you can write

```
displayformat = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                     itemsSold.Zip(ItemIDs, 
                     (items, ids) => $"{items} - {ids}").Replace(";",string.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(displayformat);
```

You can read on Enumerable.Zip in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Don't forget a final `.Replace(";", "")` on the produced string. Also the template string should be `$"{items} - {ids}"`.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for pointing out, have changed it accordingly

Comment: The Replace() is only needed at all because of the sloppy Split() earlier in the question code, but c'est la vie

Comment: @AnuViswan - I'd just do the `.Replace(...)` once at the end. Keep the code cleaner. Just a suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Distinct() key word.
hold the value into list and filter by Distinct()