# How to list players in room in Photon?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to list player's names who are in the room but how I can do that?

```
 public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
 {
     otherplayers.text = ??????
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

As the [Photon API documentation](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html) describes, you can use:

- `PhotonNetwork.PlayerList`: "A sorted copy of the players-list of the current room."
- `PhotonNetwork.PlayerListOthers`: "A sorted copy of the players-list of the current room, excluding this client."

Photon says, "This is using Linq, so better cache this value."

To go through these, use e.g.:

```
foreach (Player player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList) 
{
    print(player.NickName);
}
```

Comment: thanks but what I should use for the show that with text? otherplayers.text = ???

Comment: Depending on how you want to output this, you can concatenate a string inside the loop. You can either use the StringBuilder class or declare a string above the loop (e.g. `string s = "";`) and then in the loop, use `s += player.NickName + System.Environment.NewLine;`, or even better e.g. add it to a `List` first, then Join that list later with a given separator.

Comment: @Philiplenssen but doesn't work or I doing wrong, can you post that as an answer?

Comment: Here's some [more ways to build the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638044/appending-a-string-in-a-loop-in-effective-way). If you tried something, you may wanna show your code so it's easier to see what may be going wrong.

Comment: my problem is not from that and also I used other ways but I guess the problem is from player.NickName;

Comment: I'm used this way  ('public Text Enemy;')  and Enemy.text = player.NickName;

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like **this**:

```
void OnPhotonPlayerConnected(PhotonPlayer otherPlayer)
{
  UpdatePlayerList ();
}

void OnPhotonPlayerDisconnected(PhotonPlayer otherPlayer)
{
  UpdatePlayerList ();
}
```

Comment: so I should use public void UpdatePlayerList() { otherplayers.text = What should I put here? }

Comment: also I got this error => namespace name `PhotonPlayer' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: try `Photon.Realtime.Player` instead of `PhotonPlayer`